# Cannot inflate my viewNotesFragment.in viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My code

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
package io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter
import io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad.presenter.viewNotes.ViewNotes

class PagerAdapter(val fm: FragmentManager) :
FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment{

        return when(position){
            0 -> addToDo()
            1 -> ViewToDo()
            else -> ViewToDo()
        }
    }
    
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when(position){
            0 -> "ViewNotes()1"
            1 -> "ViewToDo()2"
            else -> "ViewToDo()3"
        }
    }

}
```

My Fragment:

```
package io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad.presenter.viewNotes

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad.R
import io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad.databinding.FragmentViewnotesBinding
import io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad.domain.model.Note

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ViewNotes : Fragment() {
var isAdNotShown:Boolean=true
val viewModel: ViewNotesViewModel by viewModels()
override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
val binding: FragmentViewnotesBinding =DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this.requireActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewnotes)
var context=this
val recyclerView=binding.recyclerview
var list:List\<Note\> = mutableListOf()
viewModel.onEvent(event.loadAd(this.requireContext(), binding.adView))
var adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(list)
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())

        viewModel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
            Log.d("check",it.toString())
            list=it
            var adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(list)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.onEvent(event.newNoteFab(this.requireContext()))
        }
        return binding.root

}}
```

Error Showing:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad, PID: 24071
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08021a (io.lionpswn.kodular.notepad:id/viewPager) for fragment ViewToDo{df73341} (911e855d-2d18-427e-b76e-f31ad6ae5083 id=0x7f08021a tag=android:switcher:2131231258:1)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:547)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1839)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1751)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:249)
at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7105)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:833)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7105)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7105)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7105)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7105)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7105)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:767)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26010)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3629)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2407)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2673)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2129)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8625)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1034)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1019)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7912)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

It is expected to inflate my viewNotes layout correctly at runtime.It is showing no view found for id even there is my correct layout file.I dont know much about ViewPager.But seeems the code is correct.Someone help me to solve this problem.I can inflate other blank fragments.But it seems to be a problem of my viewNNotes Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

getCount() method returns the number of available views. You should always return the size of list of fragments you are going to show in a viewPager. For your case try returning 3 from getCount().

```
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which viewpager are you using ViewPager or ViewPager2?
If you are using ViewPager , dont use layout manager.
It will be good if you post xml code also.